# Sharing Dictionary with UIActivityViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm new to Swift. I'm in process of making a shopping list app. There are two UITextField, one for the item name and the other for the item quantity that saves to the dictionary. I would like to share this list with UIActivityViewController, but it only shares the last value. Can someone advice me how to share all item and amount with the UIActivityViewController.

```
var shoppinglist = [String:String]()

@IBOutlet weak var Item: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var Amount: UITextField!

@IBAction func Add(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var item = Item.text!
    var amount = Amount.text!
    shoppinglist [item] = amount
    print(shoppinglist)
     }

@IBAction func share(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shoppinglist], applicationActivities: nil)
    present(activityController,animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. I hope this coding helps for you.

```
class shoppinglist:NSObject {
var yourItem:String = ""
var amount:Int = 0
  init(yourItem:String, amount:Int) {
    self.yourItem = yourItem
    self.amount = amount
  }
}
```

Declare the variables inside your class

```
var shoppingListArray = [shoppinglist]()
@IBOutlet weak var Item: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Amount: UITextField!

@IBAction func Add(_ sender: UIButton) {
   self.shoppingListArray.append(shoppinglist(yourItem:Item.text, amount:Int(Amount.text!)!))
   print(shoppingListArray)
}

@IBAction func share(_ sender: UIButton) {
  let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shoppingListArray, applicationActivities: nil)
  present(activityController,animated: true,completion: nil)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
     @IBAction func share(_ sender: UIButton) {
      let activityVc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["here your item name","item quantity"], applicationActivities:nil)

    activityVc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(activityVc, animated:true, completion:nil)

     }
```